# TYPO3 Extbase m:m relation within TCA

Tags: typo3, extbase

I'm currently struggling with a m:m relation within a simple custom TYPO3 extension.

There are multiple filters and about a dozen of categories a filter can be related to. The relation consists of the category being selected within the filter:

[image: Filter-Category-Relation]

Now, there are about 150 filters and all categories show all filters when assigning them to a product, **but should only show those filters that are associated to that categor**y.

[image: Filters]

I could not find any documentation about this, my current TCA setup looks like this:

```
'filter_bauwerkszustand' => array(
        'exclude' => 0,
        'label' => 'Bauwerkszustand',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'select',
            'renderType' => 'selectMultipleSideBySide',
            'foreign_table' => 'tx_produkte_domain_model_filter',
            'foreign_table_where' => ' AND tx_produkte_domain_model_filter.filterkategorie = 1 AND tx_produkte_domain_model_filter.sys_language_uid=###REC_FIELD_sys_language_uid### ORDER BY tx_produkte_domain_model_filter.titel ASC',
            'MM' => 'tx_produkte_filter_filterkategorie_mm',
            'size' => 10,
            'autoSizeMax' => 10,
            'maxitems' => 9999,
            'multiple' => 0,
        ),
    ),
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. What is your question exactly?

Comment: @KamiYang How to properly edit the TCA to only show the correct filters for a category. It currently shows all filters in the backend to chose from.

Comment: Whats the reason for keeping these all in the same table? If you're dealing with separate entities, they should have been split into three tables, bauwerkszustand, eigenschaften and ziel instead of keeping having them all in filterkategorie. Regardless, you need to reflect the difference in the table rows somehow and then extend the "foreign_table_where"-clause to match that.

Comment: @j4k3 "you need to reflect the difference in the table rows somehow ..." That's exactly the problem I'm having – how to do that within the TCA?

Comment: I just now noticed that you already tired defining a filterkategorie in the foreign_table_where clause. The information I gather from your snippets is a bit confusing. Is the type of realtion between filter and filtercategory a 1:n or n:m one?

Comment: @j4k3 One filter can have multiple categories, so 1:n. But the TCA is configured to only allow one selection as category within the filter, as seen in the first screenshot.

Comment: You mean "each filter can have multiple categories" - its a n:m then.

Answer (score 0):

If its a MM-relation thats the problem: the relation colum in filter doesnt acutally hold the categories, just the count of relations. The actual relations are reflected in a MM-table. The backend incorporates the categories in a `SELECT` statement with `JOIN`s, first to the MM-table, and from there to the actual categories, like so:

```
tx_produkte_domain_model_filter.uid =
tx_produkte_filter_filterkategorie_mm.uid_local

tx_produkte_filter_filterkategorie_mm.uid_foreign =
tx_produkte_domain_model_filterkategorie.uid
```

Try relacing the `tx_produkte_domain_model_filter.filterkategorie = 1` part in the query with `tx_produkte_filter_filterkategorie_mm.uid_foreign = 1`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that throws an error: "Unknown column 'tx_produkte_filter_filterkategorie_mm.uid_foreign' in 'where clause'. Es ist ein SQL-Fehler aufgetreten. Dies kann auf eine Schema-Abweichung zwischen TCA und der Datenbank hindeuten. Versuchen Sie im Install Tool einen Datenbank-Vergleich durchzuführen."

Comment: Damn, that is unfortunate. I was sure the MM-table would be joined in the query. Thats a dead end then, I guess, because I know of no way to debug the Query built from the TCA configuration. Well. You still have the option to write a user function to gather the Selectbox options, as described in this blog post, and define your own query: 
http://blog.systemfehler.net/typo3-tca-feld-mit-userfunc-benutzen/